# I want to create a dynamic tab in a dynamic tab with angular material

Tags: angular, routes, tabs, angular-material

I'm new to angular material.

I'm trying to create a dynamic tab in a dynamic tab.
I have in my example a tab that contains Food and Home.
In Food, I would like to be able to add a tab that contains Cheese and Chicken.

Is it possible to do that?

I tried to reproduce an example: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-163emj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html)

Is it possible that it's a routing problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Improve your question, add some more information to solve this issue. do you want to add (Increase) tabs dynamically?

Comment: In my example, if I click on the food tab, I would like another tab to open underneath with cheese and chicken. 
Header includes food and home.
Food includes cheese and chicken. 
In Header, I have created a dynamic tab that includes Home and Food.
I would like Food to have a dynamic tab that includes cheese and chicken.

Comment: Got it !! posted answers for this, try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity in your routing file, you have been registered **`FoodComponent`** routing in Both **`HeaderModule`** and **`FoodModule`** 
And you declared **`FoodComponent, CheeseComponent, ChickenComponent, HomeComponent`** twise (In **`HeaderModule`** and **`FoodComponentModule`**) -- A component can be declared **only once**

I made few changes to your example code please have a at look this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jf9y8u)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Indeed I still have to work on my statements. It's much clearer thanks to you.
I changed my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to load the `FoodComponent` ***eagerly*** as mentioned here :

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, MatTabsModule, RouterModule.forChild([

   //...

      { path: 'food', component: FoodComponent, data: { label: 'Food' } }, //<-- this 

   //....
export class HeaderModule { }
```

There is no reason for the router's config in `header.module.ts`.
Thus, either you load it ***lazily*** or merely bring what you'd configured in `food.module.ts` to `header.module.ts` as:

```
    @NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, MatTabsModule, RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: HeaderComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { label: 'Home' } },
      { path: 'food', component: FoodComponent, data: { label: 'Food' }, children: [

         { path: '', redirectTo: 'cheese' },
         { path: 'cheese', component: CheeseComponent, data: { label: 'Cheese' } },
         { path: 'chicken', component: ChickenComponent, data: { label: 'Chicken' } },

       ] }
    ] }
  ]) ],
  declarations: [ HeaderComponent, HomeComponent, FoodComponent, CheeseComponent, ChickenComponent ]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

---

***PS:*** Do not forget to import relevant components + there are some other minor fixes in your code I did not mentioned them, @Akhil's answer underlined some of them.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I'll be more careful next time in my component statements. I was just wondering if it was possible to declare all my routes in header.module.ts